# how to make a database available to the whole world to run application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, windows

i want to make a database that will be available to everyone that downloads an app of mine so that i can keep accounts and stats in it.Is there a way to do it for free?(for example not localhost or 127.0.0.1 but codingbot.com for connection string )

Comment: Not for free. Domain names cost money and the machine to run your database on costs money (unless you can fit it in e.g. Amazon AWS's or Azure's free tier).

Comment: hey akx thanks for answering!!i would like to ask 1 thing though,is there a way to run it on one of my pcs that i dont use for free?(like a server i guess)

Comment: Yes, if your ISP allows it and you're able to configure your local network to accept connections from the internet to it.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. You have to make your IP static to be accessible by everyone. You request to ISP to make your IP static. Suppose you have SQL Server Database. You have to forward Port 1433 in your router .

Comment: ok thxn everyone for the help!!i will try it as soon as i can and i ll come back for update